# Anaconda move to Python 3

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to make my Anaconda Python 2 into Python 3 on my Mac, and have been trying almost everything now. Preferably I would want to move to 3.6 but I am yet to manage to get any Python 3 version working. I started with `conda install python=3.6` but got dependency errors. Then I though if I download the Anaconda installer maybe it will update everything and there will be no more dependency errors, but the installation program told me to run `conda update anaconda`. I still get dependency errors though. This is what I get right now:

For version 3.6:

```
$ conda install python=3.6
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - argcomplete -> python 3.3* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - argcomplete -> python 3.3* -> xz 5.0.5
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

and for version 3.5:

```
$ conda install python=3.5
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports_abc -> python 3.4*
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What am I doing wrong and what must I do? (also, why is this so complicated?)

---

**Update:** Inspired by https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install I tried uninstalling like:

```
$ anaconda-clean -y
Backup directory: /Users/jonathan/.anaconda_backup/2017-04-24T160137
```

followed by the installation program again. The installation failed, anaconda is still supposed to be installed...

Answer (score 3):

I know that you have uninstalled and reinstalled but you can create environments with other versions of Python.

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6 anaconda
source activate py36
```

This would create an environment with Python 3.6 and all of the default packages in Anaconda.

Comment: ah yea but I am running Python from within Eclipse and I don't know how to make Eclipse run an environment like that so I think I had to update the actual standard installation?

Answer (score 2):

You can always create different versions of python in different folders. Simply specify the python version you want to use in a NEW folder. And then activate it.

```
conda create -n myProject python=3
source activate myProject
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the anaconda directory and reinstalling.